# Move elements between lists by index number?

Tags: list, prolog, element, move

I'm trying to move elements between Lists in LoL (list-of-list) structure.
I can figure out how to select the list and move the elements, but I'm lost on how to reconstruct the resulting LoL back.
Here is partial function :

```
 move(From, To, State=[P1,P2,P3], NewState=[NP1, NP2, NP3]) :- 
    nth1(From, State, FL), nth1(To, State, TL), move_elem(FL, TL, NewFL, NewTL),
   .....whats here?...
   .. NewState should be build out of NewTL,NewFL and one of P1,P2,P3...
   .. the order of the lists should be preserved..
```

`move_elem/4` is implemented. `From` & `To` are integers and specify the lists-at-position that will participate in the move op.

Currently LoL is list of 3 lists, but I would like it in the future to parametrize the number of lists.

> State is LoL before the move, NewState is the LoL after the move.

```
?- move_elem([1,2,3], [4,5,6], F,T).
F = [2, 3],
T = [1, 4, 5, 6].
```

---

nth1/3 seems to be working OK.

```
?- L=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], nth1(2,L,El).
L = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
El = [3, 4].
```

---

move() shold move element from one of the three lists to another.
From and To are the index-of-the-lists f.e.

```
LoL = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
move(1,3, LoL, NewLoL)
NewLoL = [[2],[3,4],[1,5,6]]

move(2,1, LoL, NewLoL)
NewLoL = [[3,1,2],[4],[1,5,6]]
```

move the top element from list-1 to list-3.

Comment: What's the purpose behind `State=[P1,P2,P3]` as an argument to the predicate? You should know that Prolog does not evaluate operators inline as arguments. So this just represents the term `'='(State, [P1,P2,P3])`. Is that what you intended? And can you give a more concrete example of what `move/4` behavior (example query and results)?

Comment: at the moment those are just placeholders, i gave it so you can deduce the expected structure, but they can be scrapped if not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`length/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=length/2) and [`append/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=append/3):

```
move(From, To, State, NewState):-
  length([_|HState], From),
  length([_|HNewState], To),
  append(HState, [[Item|L]|TState], State),
  append(HState, [L|TState], MState),
  append(HNewState, [NL|TNewState], MState),
  append(HNewState, [[Item|NL]|TNewState], NewState).
```

The idea is to use `length/2` to produce a list on uninstantiated variables of length From-1 and another of length To-1 (thus we skip one element from the lists of length From and To).

Then `append/3` can be used to split State in two parts or to concatenate two lists.

The first call to append will split State in a list HState of From-1 elements, and a second list with the rest. The first element from the rest is further split in two parts (the item to move and the rest of that element).

The second call to append joins the two parts excluding the item to be moved.

The third and fourth calls to append repeat this idea though this time they are used to add the moved item to the target location.

Comment: my head hurts :), can you elaborate on the mechanics on how this work,  esp length-trick. Does my comments capture some points at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `move/4` in this way:

```
appendHead(T,H,[H|T]).
removeHead([_|T],T).

insert(_,_,_,_,_,[],[]).
insert(C,I2,L1,L2,C,[_|TI],[L1|TO]):-
    C1 is C+1,
    insert(C,I2,L1,L2,C1,TI,TO).
insert(I1,C,L1,L2,C,[_|TI],[L2|TO]):-
    C1 is C+1,
    insert(I1,C,L1,L2,C1,TI,TO).
insert(I1,I2,L1,L2,C,[HI|TI],[HI|TO]):-
    I1 \= C,
    I2 \= C,
    C1 is C+1,
    insert(I1,I2,L1,L2,C1,TI,TO).

move(I1,I2,LIn,LOut):-
    nth1(I1,LIn,L1),
    nth1(I2,LIn,L2),
    nth1(1,L1,E1),
    removeHead(L1,L1R),
    appendHead(L2,E1,L2F),
    insert(I1,I2,L1R,L2F,1,LIn,LOut).

?- LoL = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], move(1,3, LoL, NewLoL).
LoL = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]],
NewLoL = [[2], [3, 4], [1, 5, 6]].
false.

?- LoL = [[2], [3, 4], [1, 5, 6]], move(2,1, LoL, NewLoL).
LoL = [[2], [3, 4], [1, 5, 6]],
NewLoL = [[3, 2], [4], [1, 5, 6]].
false.

?- LoL = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], move(2,1, LoL, NewLoL).
NewLoL = [[3,1,2],[4],[1,5,6]].
false.
```

If you want to prevent backtracking, just add a cut `!` after each definition of `insert/4` (you will not get `false`).

Answer (score 0):

Prolog does a depth-first search, meaning it will try to reach a goal by exploring all possible paths to a solution. Every time there are multiple paths available, it creates a choice point and then works its way down through the choices top to bottom. That means, if a choice immediately fails, the next will be called. This allows you to create the paths very clearly and you can give it choices to make. All atoms including lists are effectively immutable in Prolog. What you want to do is construct a second list from the first, possibly in a different order or with less elements, more elements, replaced elements etc.

I'm using replacement of a cell in a row with a cell(point(X,Y),Value) coordinate in a matrix as an example here. The three choices for rebuilding a list.

1. End of the list has been reached, this is the end condition and ends the new list.
2. The first cell of the list is checked and the coordinate doesn't match the replacement, so it's placed as is in the new list.
3. The first cell of the list does match the coordinate so place the element in the new list and close it off by adding the remaining unchecked elements as the tail.

This results in the code:

```
%coordinate not found, return the list as is
replace_cell(_,_,[],[]).
%no match, X already extracted from Element to reduce calls 
replace_cell(X, Element, [RowElement|Tail], [RowElement|NewTail]) :-
    RowElement \= cell(point(X,_),_),
    replace_cell(X, Element, Tail, NewTail).
%match
replace_cell(X, Element, [cell(point(X,_),_)|Tail], [Element|Tail]).
```

This is the standard recursion you're probably used to. A goal is set, an answer is reached and Prolog starts stepping back through the calls made, filling in the variables we left open as it steps back. Then those filled variables become the output to the next returned call.

To then do it with multiple layers of lists, we just need to figure out which list we need to pass to the next, more specific call. In this matrix example, it's a square so all columns share an X and all rows share an Y coordinate. To figure out which row we need, we can feed the entire matrix into a simple predicate which checks the Y. Note that we aren't actually modifying the matrix yet, just identifying the row. This is mostly to keep the code readable.

```
%are there any rows left?
move_to_row(_, [], []).
%is element's Y equal to row Y?
move_to_row(Y, [Row|_], Row) :- Row = [cell(point(_,Y),_)|_].
%move to next row
move_to_row(Y,[_|Tail], Row) :- move_to_row(Y,Tail,Row).
```

After replacing the element in the row, since we have both the old and the new row we can identify the old row and reconstruct the matrix with the new row.

```
replaceElement(_,_,[],[]).
replaceElement(Replacable, Replacement, [Item|List], [Replacable|NewList] ) :-
   Item \= Replacable,
   replaceElement(Replacable, Replacement, List, NewList),
replaceElement(Replacable, Replacement, [Replacable|List], [Replacement|List] ) :- 
   !.
```

So effectively, the position in the list is kept by the order in which we step through the list on the way down, and then the new list is rebuilt on the way up.

For list `[1,2,3]`, `[Head|Tail]` gives us `Head = 1, Tail = [2,3]`. If we then call `[Head|Tail]` again, it gives us `Head = 2, Tail = [3]`. On the way back, the exact opposite happens and the Head is appended to the front of the Tail. By visualizing each layer of lists as its own identifiable type and giving them their own identifier, it should be fairly simple to go through them efficiently irregardless of how many lists within lists you want to nest. The matrix is a 2d rectangle, but for example by having the coordinates within `cell` as a list and adding a Z axis it can fairly easily be turned into a cube or something even more complex with more than 3 dimensions.